# Closing vs Migration

Tags: discussion, migration, closed-questions

Just curious. Generally when I see a closed or migrated question, the reasoning seems sound. This one caught my eye, however, and made me wonder if I've been wrong in my assumptions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770607/php-fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found-in

What were the criteria here for closing the question as "Off-Topic", as opposed to migrating to SF? Seemed a valid question to me, yet it was closed just a day after it was asked. Is the lack of immediate answers the problem?

Not trying to challenge the decision - as I said, just curious :-)

Comment: I don't really think the question is on topic on Server Fault, [anything in a home setting is off topic as per their FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: Yeah, they do seem to concentrate on the more serious stuff, I guess. Maybe not SF, then. But I dunno, I feel like it should belong *somewhere*. I don't think it's the greatest question ever asked, but nor do I think it is anything like one of the worst, either. Still puzzled. Maybe I have too much time on my hands.

Comment: Well, if it belongs anywhere, it's Stack Overflow. I did a small edit (approval pending) and moved all extra info the OP gave in comments in the question. Can't promise it's going to be enough to get the question re-opened, but in general it would be helpful to try to get a question in the best shape possible before you bring it up on Meta.

Comment: Okay, thanks. In future I'll be more proactive. I didn't want to barge in and start making a noise if the reasoning for the closing was sound, that's all.

Comment: I'm puzzled by off topic as well, there are quite a few very similar questions. A duplicate closing would be more appropriate and perhaps "not a real question" applies as well (the question is a bit vague), but I can't understand off topic.

Answer (score 3):

I have been an ordinary member for stack overflow for more than a year.

I personally think of the following reason for such closing

1. Question undefined. The author never explain why he or she need to carry out such configuration. Unable of using php_mysqli can be every possible reasons.
2. The author has no manner. Etiquette is important. Respect among others is a must. Every time when you ask a question , it is encouraging for users to answer the question but more importantly, it is reasonable for users not to answer the questions. They have their own things to deal with.  On the other hand, he always starting with "I" and "Can you". That explicitly implies his selfish nature and takes the help for granted. Such attitude shall never be encouraged in the community.
3. The way to describe the questions is wrong too. He uses too many jargons and configuration standards rather than describing the case and events. That makes a serious headache for other users to understand the question of the author.

In conclusion , ill-defined questions,no manner, wrong approach to ask questions are the reasons to close posts

Comment: I agree with #1, the question was not specific. However I think it is clear the OP has a specific issue he is working towards solving. He also listed what he has tried, which shows effort. With regards to #2, I don't think the OP's first language is English; I didn't read it as being particularly abrupt or selfish when taking that fact into account. I have seen some *incredibly* rude posters on SO, and I don't think this is such a case. As for #3, well, perhaps you're right, except that the commenters clearly knew what he was talking about enough to respond. Still don't see why "Off-Topic" :-/

Comment: What about if the comments drive out of the focus of the question? It seems unrelated comments are the culprit for off-topic closing

Comment: That's certainly a valid point, and I can remember several cases where that happened. The thing is, I think the comments to this particular question are not doing that. They are trying to get more information out of the OP so they can create a solution (or so it seems to me). (I swear I'm not trying to be obtuse, I just want to understand....)

Comment: I have also found out one more thing, the author seems to answer the post on his or her own consecutively. Can this be a valid reason too ?

Comment: I suppose, but doesn't that seem more like a style issue? The OP is not familiar with the etiquette of SO comments and so just keeps adding them whenever a thought occurs to him, for example. If that is the case, and it is a style issue, I don't think it affects the subject of the question - so IMHO it doesn't really justify "Off-Topic". Perhaps there is simply no closing reason available that was more applicable? I guess that could be it.